# Trouble in obtaining correct geometric transformation of cartesian coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I am working in python and i have previous `(x_prev,y_prev) = (1.5, 3)` coordinate and current `(x,y) = (2, 3.2)`coordinate and `angle` difference between them and i want the next coordinate to be at a certain distance `d` with the same orientation as the current `(x,y)`coordinate. I have tried using the rotation and translation formula but it fails to give the proper answer. here is the code so far what i tried.

```
d = 0.5
angle = np.arctan2((y - y_prev), (x - x_prev))
x_ = x * np.cos(angle) - y * np.sin(angle) + (d * np.sinc(angle_/2)* np.cos(angle/2))
y_ = x * np.sin(angle) + y * np.cos(angle) + (d * np.sinc(angle_/2)* np.sin(angle/2))
```

the expected coordinate is approximately `(x_,y_) = (2.5, 3.6)` with the same orientation as the current but it results in wrong coordinate so is there anything i am missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the variable `angle_` inside `np.sinc()`?

Comment: it is a typo mistake. It is the same angle

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are asking. What is `angle` and why do you call it angle difference between two points? What is the distance `d`? Distance from what? What is the orientation? Orientation compared to what? In any case this question has nothing to do with programming but with geometry. So it should be asked at some mathematics forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about geometry, not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partly agree with [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159077/trouble-in-obtaining-correct-geometric-transformation-of-cartesian-coordinates#comment73399281_43159077) that your question is a geometrical one. However, I'm adding an answer because numpy lets you avoid all that trigonometric work that you are trying to do in the first place.

What you want is to find the point `(x_new,y_new)` based on `(x_prev,y_prev)` and `(x_now,y_now)` such that the three points lie on the same line and the distance between `(x_prev,y_prev)` and `(x_new,y_new)` is a preset `d`.

You don't need trigonometry if you can work with proper two-dimensional vectors. You can normalize the vector `(x_now,y_now) - (x_prev,y_prev)` to get an orientation vector of the line along which you need to move from `(x_prev,y_prev)` in order to end up at `(x_new,y_new)`. Numpy lets you handle this elegantly:

```
import numpy as np

x_prev,y_prev = (1.5, 3)
x_now,y_now = (2, 3.2)
d = 0.5

# use 2d arrays for elegant vector operations
# of course we can directly define these from coordinates if we want to
p_prev = np.array([x_prev,y_prev])
p_now = np.array([x_now,y_now])

# compute the unit direction vector for p_new - p_prev
t = p_now - p_prev
t /= np.linalg.norm(t) # use Euclidean norm by default

# p_new is simple now:
p_new = p_prev + d*t

print(p_prev)
print(p_now)
print(p_new)
```

The above results in `(x_new,y_new)=(1.96423835,3.18569534)`. Your points are actually such that `(x_now,y_now)` is almost at `0.5` distance from `(x_prev,y_prev)`, so the resulting vector is hardly different from the original one. But anyway, the above procedure will always give you a new point which is at the same angle from `(x_prev,y_prev)` as `(x_now,y_now)` but at the fixed distance.